# Why chrome browser is changing endpoint frequently

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, service-worker

I’m developing chrome push notification for my web site and doing the development in localhost (local machine) environment.  Sending push notification is success with specific endpoint which I got when I subscribe the notification first time. I use same endpoint  for all push messages.

Here sometime push notification got failed due to endpoint mismatch. When I see in chrome console (debugging mode) there was different endpoint.
Why chrome browser is changing endpoint? In this case how do we handle this scenario and update the new endpoint in the db?

sample endpoint:
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send/AWERdvfdfdsfdobRH4zlXGuyeuie3543uTBuP6air5dzZfltNa-FKF6K6S-9P5SdfbCbyvn9RdsfsdvU1XwSBwIrekjdK6_i4Cg-5rZAj8UvL1s-Bbr61yvvt_y2Hg9RdsyV

when i check next time, above endpoint got changed as like below
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send/reytryMkQwtY:YTUNMdsjjfhsdf349851VS6McDE7s_GITe_djsgfdkjghcdfdfgdftrkddfdsXiwX1vP_XclmDqrKPOAMJDfsYYXdhMX164694Q&ksdhfksdfhkjfhksdcndsk

Thank you.

Comment: How are you retrieving the endpoint? If you have a valid subscription, `getSubscription()` should return the same endpoint. (`subscribe()` can return a different endpoint.)

Comment: hello mjs, im using getsubscription() but its not always changing. here i have clarification, end user already allowed for notification and got endpoint and stored into db. again if you use subscribe() to get endpoint whether we will get different endpoint?

Comment: I don't think the endpoint should change from one `getSubscription()` to another. (Provided the client doesn't unsubscribe.) If you can reproduce this I would log it as a bug in Chrome. (Especially if FF doesn't behave in the same way.)

Comment: Calling .pushManager.subscribe again for an already suscribed( permission granted) user will return a different endpoint?

Comment: well it doesn't change however in google chrome mobile cleaning the history and cookies change it

Answer (score 0):

The push notification endpoint is dependant on the service-worker. When a service-worker is unregistered and created again, the `PushManager.getSubscription()` method will indeed return `null`. You then need to call `subscribe()` again, which will return a new endpoint.

If you server tries to send a push notification to the first endpoint after the service-worker was unregistered, you will get a `NotRegistered` (for Chrome) or a `Gone` (for Firefox) error. So make sure to register the new endpoint as soon as the app loads or the device may become unreachable.

Note that this does not seem to affect service-worker updates.